# toSeq behaving differently from to[Seq]

Tags: scala, collections

I was surprised to find that using `to[Col]` the default implementation for `Seq` is `Vector` and not `List`:

```
val x = Seq(1, 2, 3)  // -> List(1, 2, 3)
x.toSeq               // -> List(1, 2, 3)
x.to[Seq]             // -> Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `to` method is defined on `GenTraversableOnce[A]`:

```
def to[Col[_]](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, Col[A]]): Col[A]
```

The problem being that `GenTraversableOnce` doesn't have a `Repr` type. Thus:

```
implicitly[CanBuildFrom[Nothing, Int, Seq[Int]]].apply.result  // Vector()
```

whereas

```
implicitly[CanBuildFrom[Seq[Int], Int, Seq[Int]]].apply.result // List()
```

I would count this as a bug, actually. It could only be solved by moving the method to `GenTraversableLike` (?). Opinions?

Comment: Note: Scala Collections overhaul will remove `CanBuildFrom`, and it would be `to(Seq)`.